# Make an attribute as node name in Cypher - Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, attributes, cypher, nodes

I have to write CQL (Cypher Query Language) where I need to have one of the attributes of a node as the node name. I am loading data from a CSV file.
For example -

> CREATE(**attribute_name1**: Item {**attribute_name1**: item.attribute_name1,attribute_name2:item.attribute_name2})")

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your mention of "the node name" worries me a bit here.

You have bolded two things here...the property key of "attribute_name1", and the variable for this node (right before `:Item`).

[Node variables](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/variables/) are never saved to the database. They are purely so you can reuse the node later within the same query by referencing it by the variable.